# Is ちの a verb stem in ツリ目がちの?

Tags: words

From 《君の名は。 (角川つばさ文庫) (新海 誠;ちーこ)》,

> まだ十歳くらいか、ツインテールでツリ目がちの、生意気そうな子どもだ。

My inferred translation:

> She was a kid with slanted eyes and a pony tail who looked like she
> was around 10 years old and cocky.

But I don't know what role ちの plays or how it changes my translation.

There is also no usage found for this vocab word on jisho: https://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%84%E3%83%AA%E7%9B%AE%20%23sentences

But I did find two usages for 目がち: https://jisho.org/search/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1%20%23sentences

However, when I look up verbs for ち I can't seem to find anything that fits with eye (unless I am misunderstanding the sentence): https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A1%20

Comment: A couple notes -- ツインテール is literally "twin tail", i.e. not just the one bunch in the back that you get with a "pony tail", but rather one on each side of the head like you get with "pig tails".  Also, the term you're asking about is [釣【つ】り眼【め】](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%8A%E3%82%8A%E7%9B%AE%EF%BC%8F%E9%87%A3%E3%82%8A%E7%9C%BC) + [勝ち【がち】](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1) + の.  HTH!

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Thanks for the additional information. Can you please let me know if I have the right understanding:  釣り眼 + 勝ち would mean really ("seriously") slant eyed right?

Comment: I think you have the right of it.  See also the #2 usage example in [the E<>J entry on Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1).

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42594/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70473/9831

Comment: There wasn't an official answer so I included both of your comments and made one. Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Eiríkr Útlendi for guiding me to the answer. I will summarize it for everyone's convenience down below:

If you search がち but nothing appears in the dictionary, please make sure you include the Kanji.

がち stands for 勝ち which has the following [definitions (weblio)](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A1):

> がち
>
> ［形動］《俗語。「がちんこ」から》真剣に。まじめに。本気で。「がちで頭にきた」 がち【勝ち】
>
> ［接尾］名詞や動詞の連用形に付く。
>
> １ …が多い、…する傾きがある、…に傾きやすいなどの意を表す。「後れ勝ち」「病気勝ち」
>
> ２ それのほうが得をする意を表す。「早い者勝ち」
>
> [補説] 1は、かなで書くことが多い。

With that being said, it would be safe to translate `ツリ目がち` to be `with slanted eyes`. This is further supported by Chocolate's related link (伏し目がち: (na-adj) with eyes downcast).

Hope this helps.